# Which SLAM implementations support pcap input?

Tags: python, lidar, slam

I have a `.pcap` file collected from using a Velodyne VLP16 LIDAR unit. I've been looking through the different implementations of SLAM and most use camera or stereo camera inputs. I was wondering if there was an implementation that supported pcap LIDAR data.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a realtime camera looking at the road for slam! the lidar basemap can support the static layer but you still need a dynamic layer (in this case camera or a GPS/IMU).